# How to select a cell in excell based on a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to get Excel to check for the last cell in a column with a specific number, for example `824`, then select the cell `A(x)` where `X` is the row that it finds that number in. I am able to get the first half done, but I do not know that syntax for selecting a row in that specific column.

I have:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(2:1000)*(C2:C1000=824)))
```

which returns to me `184`.

So I want it to check cell `A184` so that I can compare the date in that cell with the current date.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(2:1000)*(C2:C1000=824))))
```

This will retrieve the value in column **A** in the same row as the last occurrence of 824 in column **C**.

[image]